# Can Blender be used to create a physics based game without programming?

Tags: game-engine, physics

My question is this, I want to create a dirt bike game that is more physics based then animation based.  I am brand new to the engine, and I am more of a graphic designer and not a coder, would it be possible to set physics without knowing coding?  Thanks again guys this is really awesome!

Comment: I'd suggest using Unity which is more of a real game engine. Blender plays really well with Unity as part of the asset pipeline as an added bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Blender's game engine uses a node concept for "wiring" game functionality which are called logic bricks. You can get more advanced functionality with programming in Python, but the logic bricks can do what you want if you want to avoid the programming. So yes, you can create a game without programming knowledge using Blender's game engine.

The Intro to BGE on the BlenderWiki ( http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sculptorjim/Game_Engine ) is pretty detailed on how to work with BGE and logic bricks. Blendswap also has an example with physics that you could start off with: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73536

I know of one person, SolarLune, that has been working with the BGE for quite a while, and he's got quite a few videos up concerning it if you want some tips and tricks. He just did a recent video on why he uses BGE:
youtube.com/watch?v=8ZJEupWdf30

Unity would require programming in C# (or Javascript).

Comment: Also, if you don't want to learn text-based code, the Unreal Engine has "Blueprints", which is a visual scripting language similar to Blender's shader nodes.